# Comparing columns and extracting information from them

Tags: r

I have 2 columns of data that I pulled from a dataset using this code:

```
ID <- matrix(c(df[[2]], df[[19]]), nrow = 737, ncol = 2)
```

I have uploaded a small example of this table here https://i.stack.imgur.com/XXnAG.jpg

The first column contains codes that relate to a location, the most important part of that code is the 1st 4 digits which tell me which town e.g. 6011 = Town A.

The second column is a key coded from 1 to 6 that tells me which of 6 species was found in this town.

I was hoping to find a way for R to run through these columns to produce a matrix that will tell me which species occurred in which town? So I guess the table would look something like this...

```
       |Species 1| Species 2| Species 3|   
  |Town|
  |6011|       21|         23|        15|
  |6013|       21|         23|        15|
```

So some how I need to sort through the matrix, sorting the town column by the first 4 digits, whilst at the same time counting the number of each species in the towns.

I have used `substr` function in the past to extract information from a matrix to use, but I'm not sure how to do something as complex as this.

I would really appreciate any help!
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do by:

1. creating a `data.frame` from i) the `substr` result (see `?substr`) on the first column and ii) the second column of your matrix.
2. using `table` on it.

Your example is not reproducible, so here is a matrix, `m`, that looks like yours:

```
m <- matrix(c(
  "6011-0001", "1",
  "6011-0002", "2",
  "6011-0003", "2",
  "6012-0001", "1",
  "6012-0002", "2",
  "6012-0003", "2",
  "6012-0004", "4"), ncol=2, byrow=T)
```

Then:

```
table(data.frame(town=substr(m[, 1], 1, 4), sp=m[, 2]))
```

Using a `data.frame` rather than a `matrix` would ease consequent operations.

Comment: Don't forget to +vote/accept the answer so that your question appears as resolved ;-)